# Save firefox developer tools javascript command history

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I use Developer Tools Console to run JavaScript commands. It is currently showing history of about 40-50 executed commands accessible using `Up Arrow key`.

In the history it is showing repeated commands multiple times and the earlier commands I executed 4-5 days ago have vanished.

Any Idea how to recover/save this history OR expand history to save unlimited commands (like in normal console)?

[image: Firefox Developer Tools]

Comment: What do you mean about saving unlimited commands in "normal console"? What do you consider the "normal console"? Are you sure that it's saving unlimited commands? Did you set some preference to do so?

Comment: This is the exact reason I use Firebug ❤.. so much **easier** to run code there!

Comment: Have you tried Firefox built-in [scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Scratchpad)?

Comment: @Makyen For me normal Console in firefox is -> `Crtl` + `Shft` + `K`.

Comment: @vsync I used firebug for a month or two when i stated web dev, but at the time I had read somewhere that its development had been stopped (https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13107802). But reading your comment I just checked it out again and it is being maintained. p.s. I did not know about Scratchpad till now, could be useful.

Comment: @SymfonyUser - [This is why](https://i.snag.gy/n2gkXC.jpg) I love Firebug. the ability to write code (with highlights) on one side and immediately see the result on the left side.. no browser does that in a native way :(

Comment: @SymfonyUser - `shift + F4` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way (as of Firefox 55.0.1) to specify an actually unlimited number of history items to keep. However, you can specify a larger number, up to 2147483647. To do so, go to `about:config`. Then, change the preference `devtools.webconsole.inputHistoryCount` to the integer value which you desire. The default is 50.

You can verify that there's no way to specify an unlimited size from the [source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/7ff4c2f1fe11f6b98686f783294692893b1e1e8b/devtools/client/webconsole/jsterm.js#489).

> Any Idea how to recover/save this history

There is no way to recover older, forgotten history (see source code linked above). It is forgotten.

The only way I have found to save such code (beyond what is stored in the history) is to copy and paste it into some other location. You could make a legacy add-on which made saving this history easier, but not a WebExtension. In a brief search, I did not find an already existing add-on to do so.

You can find more general information at:

- [The command line interpreter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter)
- [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)
- [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I am looking for. Let me confirm.